# PHP MSSQL - text too long and getting truncated due to freetds.conf textsize

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

My text fetched from a **MSSQL** db via **PHP** is being truncated due to the text size setting in the `freetds.conf` file. Unfortunately, `ini_set('mssqltextsize', 99999999)` and `ini_set('mssqltextlimit', 999999999)` don't work and I can't change the `freetds.conf` file.

Are there any PHP functions or database tricks to get the text returned in chunks through multiple calls (other than actually splitting up the data onto separate rows)?